# Observable with nested map doesn't return value

Tags: observable, angular5

I was trying to change the content of an observable value by combining the result of another async function call. However there was not value return.

May I know how to make this work ?

```
this.orders = this.orderSvc.getOrdersbyUser(user.uid)
        .pipe(
          map(orderList => {
            return orderList.map(order => {       
              for(let i=0; i < order.orderDetail.length; i++) {
                order.orderDetail[i] = this.getOrderDetailItem(order.orderDetail[i])
              }
              console.log(order); //has value
              return order;
            })
          })
        ) 
      this.orders.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value); //no value
      })
```

Comment: anyone has an idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting an error, try observing that,

```
this.orders.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value); //no value
}, err => console.log(err));
```